# Let $X = {x_0, x_1, · · · , x_m}$ be a subset of ${1, 2, · · · , n}$,where $m > n/2$,show that X contains two numbers b and c such that $x_0 + b = c$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $X = \{x_0, x_1,...,x_m\}$ be a subset of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ where $m>n/2$, and $x_0$ is the smallest number in $X$. Use the pigeonhole principle to show that $X$ contains two numbers $b$ and $c$ such that $x_0+b=c$.

I am not sure how to go about this problem. We were given a hint.

HINT: Consider $x_1-x_0, x_2-x_0,...,x_m-x_0$

If anyone could give helpful guidance to the problem, I'd appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint*:  There are $m$ distinct numbers from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ in the set $$D:=\{x_1-x_0,x_2-x_0,\ldots,x_m-x_0\}.$$  There are $m+1$ distinct numbers from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ in $X$.

Since $m+(m+1)>n$, we must have $$D \cap X \neq \emptyset.$$  I.e., there exists $x_i \in D$ for some $i \in \{0,1,\ldots,m\}$.  This can be used to prove $b$ and $c$ exist.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  how many numbers are in the list given in your hint?  If any of those match a number in the original list...